# In google colab, Problem using PeriodIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, datetime-format

I am running the following in google colab:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("walmart.csv")
df.head()
df.set_index('Line Item',inplace=True)
df.index = pd.PeriodIndex(df.index, freq='Q-JAN')
df
```

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/tslibs/period.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.period.extract_ordinals()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ordinal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
9 frames
ValueError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: REVENUE

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DateParseError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string_with_reso()

DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: REVENUE
```

And this is [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMmvg.png) as I see it in google colab

I want to assign quarterly time period to index.

Comment: A sample of your dataframe would be helpful – can you copy and paste the output from `df.head().to_dict()` into your question?

Comment: {'Line Item': {0: 'Revenue', 1: 'Expenses', 2: 'Profit'},
 '2017Q1': {0: 115904, 1: 86544, 2: 29360},
 '2017Q2': {0: 120854, 1: 89485, 2: 31369},
 '2017Q3': {0: 118179, 1: 87484, 2: 30695},
 '2017Q4': {0: 130936, 1: 97743, 2: 33193},
 '2017Q5': {0: 117542, 1: 87688, 2: 29854}}

Answer (score 0):

The portion of the error message that reads: `ValueError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: REVENUE` indicates that the string `REVENUE` is in your index.

This is because you're trying to set `Line Item` as your index, but based on the sample DataFrame you've provided, you want the columns `'2017Q1',...'2017Q4'` of your df to become the new index.

Try getting rid of the line `df.set_index('Line Item',inplace=True)` and everything else below, and instead try the following:

```
df_final = df.set_index('Line Item').T
```

Output:

```
Line Item  Revenue  Expenses  Profit
2017Q1      115904     86544   29360
2017Q2      120854     89485   31369
2017Q3      118179     87484   30695
2017Q4      130936     97743   33193
2017Q5      117542     87688   29854
```

However, you'll notice that the index value `'2017Q5'` is invalid. Therefore, until you ensure all of the index values have valid quarters ('Q1'-'Q4'), you won't be able to convert them to a `PeriodIndex` – as your dataframe is currently formatted, `pd.PeriodIndex(df_final.index, freq='Q')` will throw `pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.DateParseError: Incorrect quarterly string is given, quarter must be between 1 and 4: 2017Q5`